# SQL Merge Query - Executing Additional Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a working T-SQL MERGE statement. The premise is that Database A contains records about customer's support calls. If they are returning a product for repair, Database B is to be populated with certain data elements from Database A (e.g. customer name, address, product ID, serial number, etc.) So I will run an SQL Server job that executes an SSIS package every half hour or so, in which the MERGE will do one of the following:

> 1. If the support call in Database A requires a product return and it
>      is not in Database B, INSERT it into Database B..
> 2. If the support call in Database A requires a product return and it
>      is in Database B - but data has changed - UPDATE it in Database B.
> 3. If there is a product return in Database B but it is no longer
>      indicated as a product return in Database A (yes, this can happen - a customer can change their mind at a later time/date and not want to pay for a replacement product), DELETE it from Database
>      B.

My problem is that Database B has an additional table with a 1-to-many FK relationship with the table being populated in the MERGE. I do not know how, or even if, I can go about using a MERGE statement to first delete the records in the table with FK constraint before deleting the records as I am currently doing in my MERGE statement.

Obviously, one way would be to get rid of the DELETE in the MERGE and hack out writing IDs to delete in a temp table, then deleting from the FK table, then the PK table. But if I can somehow delete from *both* tables in `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` that would be cleaner code. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` into/from one table per query.

However, if you added an `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the `FK` relationship, the sub-table would be cleaned up as you delete from the primary table, and it would be handled in a single operation.

Comment: Oh, geez. I haven't used cascading FKs in so long I didn't even think of that. Back to the basics :) Thanks for pointing that out.